# Autohotkey hotstring inserts results twice

Tags: autohotkey

I have a hotstring that inserts a datestamp as shown below. It works fine, with the exception that when I type 'ds' and then a trigger (e.g. a space or tab) it doesn't actually include a space or tab, and then when I type an additional one I get another copy of the datestamp that backspaces over part of the original.

So, I type 'ds' and then space once and get: 2012-06-11. I type 'ds' and then space twice and get 2012-06-2012-06-11.

Help?

Thanks.

```
::ds:: ;DateShort
    FormatTime, CurrentDate,, yyyy-MM-dd
    SendInput %CurrentDate%
return
```

Comment: Argh. Fixed my own problem. It was affecting all hotstrings, not just the one above. Had two instances of the script running. Killed one; everything's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Knelby, It's not the script! Your script runs fine on my machine and does NOT provide TWO dates after typing ds{space}{space}, but as expected it just prints the date and then one space.
I tested this on: Win7*64 Home Premium with US keyboard layout and Dutch keyboard settings outputting in Notepad.

Just for fun, could you try this:

```
:*:ds/:: ;DateShort
```

This makes the / the end character, just to see how the script responds on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Robert. I stupidly had two instances of the script running; killing one fixed the issue. What was interesting was the result to me. I don't know exactly how AHK processes hotstrings, but I wouldn't have expected that there would have been anything for the second instance of the script to process after the first did its replacement